# catch exception in python script which calls another script

Tags: python, exception

I am running python script from another python file. is there a way I can know if an eception occurred in the second script?

EX: script1.py calls script2.py
    python script2. py -arguments
How can script1 know if an exception occurred in script2?

run.py

```
import subprocess
```

### subprocess.call("python test.py -t hi", shell=True)

test.py

```
import argparse
print "testing exception"

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='parser')
parser.add_argument('-t', "--test")

args = parser.parse_args()

print args.test
raise Exception("this is an exception")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

When a Python program throws an Exception, the process returns a non-zero return code. Subprocess functions like `call` will return the return code by default. So, to check if an exception occurred, check for a non-zero exit code.

Here is an example of checking the return code:

```
    retcode = subprocess.call("python test.py", shell=True)
    if retcode == 0:
        pass  # No exception, all is good!
    else:
        print("An exception happened!")
```

Another method would be to use [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call), which throws a  subprocess.CalledProcessError exception on a non-zero exit status. An example:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_call(["python test.py"], shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("An exception occured!!")
```

If you need to know which exception occurred in your test program, you can change the exception using exit(). For example, in your test.py:

```
try:
    pass  # all of your test.py code goes here
except ValueError as e:
    exit(3)
except TypeError as e:
    exit(4)
```

And in your parent program:

```
retcode = subprocess.call("python test.py", shell=True)
if retcode == 0:
    pass  # No exception, all is good!
elif retcode == 3:
    pass  # ValueError occurred
elif retcode == 4:
    pass  # TypeError occurred
else:
    pass  # some other exception occurred
```

Comment: @user3330263 updated answer to reflect your example code

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best method is to make script2 an actual module, import what you want from it into script1, then use the existing try/except mechanic. But perhaps that's not an option?  Otherwise I think what gets returned from os.system would probably include what you need.